# Error 404: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css

Tags: google-api, http-status-code-404, prestashop, google-font-api

One module in our Prestashop platform inserts the google link below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,regular,500,600,700,100,200,800,900%7CDM+Serif+Display:regular,italic&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext?ver=8739" type="text/css" media="all">
```

But the browser reports ERROR 404: But when I insert and check the URL into the browser manually - it works?

Does this kind of google link needs to be ref. to in a special way or does any other tags need to be added to it before it will work?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not 100% sure how I got this right by click around in the dev. console. But this URL here works:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,regular,500,600,700,100,200,800,900%7CDM+Serif+Display:regular,italic&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext?ver=7489
```